# How do I separate the content of a textbox by number without binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I want to show the numbers in TextBox with thousand separator **without** binding it and without programmatically.

Just in XAML.

like this example:

> 123456  =>  123,456 or  1000000000 => 1,000,000,000

Also this line in XAML have error:

```
<TextBox x:Name="text_main2" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:N0}}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
```

And I don't no can I do this work in TextBoxMask:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="0000"  PromptChar=" " x:Name="txtname"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="512,296,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152"/>
```

Please help

Comment: StringFormat is a property owned by the Binding.
And without setting a binding, you cannot use it.
It also won't work if the binding throws an error.
Therefore, you need to bind to a real property of the desired type.
But binding with a string format will only solve the problem of outputting in the desired form.
The user input can be anything.
If you need to format the user input, then this can only be solved through Sharpe code using a Behavior or AttachedProperty in which the TextChanged event will be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it without binding or writing additional code in general. The TextBox has no build in text/input formatting.

But in a proper WPF application you would always use data binding in order to send user input to a model that processes the input, so using `Binding.StringFormat` to format displayed values is a straight forward solution and quite flexible. It allows to format the displayed value without modifying the actual value (data).

Another solution which allows to only modify the displayed value and not the actual data, is to implement an `IValueConverter` and assign it to `Binding.Converter`.

Other options involve subclassing `TextBox` (like your `MaskedTextBox` type) or creating an attached behavior. The goal should be to format the number for display without modifying the actual value.

To fix the error you have I suggest to fix your binding. You didn't explained what kind of error you get. But at least your Binding needs a fix.
You can't just set the property StringFormat. This is not how MarkupExtensions work. Binding MarkupExtension has a constructor that requires a Binding.Path value (except you use the default constructor which uses the default value, which resolves to the current DataContext). You can't omit it.
So, if you want to set a property on Bindng without specifying a Path (because you want to use the implicit binding source to the DataContex you can use the '.' (period)  notation:

`{Binding}` is equivalent to `{Binding Path=.}`.

So to fix the binding expression it should be:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" />
```

## Example

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Registe(
    "NumericValue",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(int), MainWindow.OnNumericValueChanged));

  public int NumericValue
  {
    get => (int) GetValue(MainWindow.NumericValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.NumericValueProperty, value);
  }

  // Property changed callbacck
  private static void OnNumericValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var textBox = d as TextBox;
    int newValue = (int) e.NewValue;

    // Do something with the new value that was entered by the user
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // Set DataContext to the MainWindow itself
    this.DataContext = this;

    // We want 10000 to be displayed with thousands number groups
    // like '10.000'
    this.NumericValue = 10000;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>

  <!-- Display number with thousands groups. Note that 'N0' will truncate decimal places (zero deimal places) -->
  <TextBox Text="{Binding NumericValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" />
</Window>
```

Recomended read:

- [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)
- [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: can you write me a full example about it ?

Comment: What didn't work? Do you still have an error? Make sure that the binding source is a numeric type like `int`.

Comment: no any error its not doing any thing just that  like 1000=> 1000 ?!

Comment: The data source must be int or double (or any type that implements IFormatable to be prices). If your binding source is a string that it won't work as string does not implement IFormatable.

Comment: can you show me a example of binding for this

Comment: There are many ways. Better you update your question to show how you bind and then we can fix it.

Comment: my problem is binding , I don't no how to create a data context for a textbox for binding it

Comment: I have no binding

Comment: But in your code you bound the Text property to some source?

Comment: that's empty because of I don't have binding However, thank you for taking the time to answer this question

Comment: Ok, where do you want to use the TextBox value, in code-behind?

Comment: I have added a small example. It's written here in the editor, so it may contain some errors llike typos.

Comment: Thank you so much but how to format in TextChange because its just show a number from binding not when user typing text

Comment: It will also work when you type in input. You just have to remove focus from the TextBox e.g. by clicking on a different control (make the caret disappear). After the TextBox lost focus it the binding will format the value.

Comment: for last  a littlie problem how can I use it for many textbox because now with that way I cannot do this for multi textbox

Comment: You can set a Binding with the StringFormat assigned on the Text property for each TextBox. The binding path must point to a property of a numeric type (or a type that implements IFormatable), like int or double. Otherwise you would have to write a IValueConverter implementation.